# documentBuilder.parse fails under android 4.0.3

Tags: android

I my application, documentBuilder.parse(inputStream) throws the following error 
in Android 4.0.3.

```
"SAXException : Unexpected token (position:TEXT ?xml version='1....@1:38 in java.io.InputStreamReader@419ae708)"
```

The same code is working in all the older versions of android.

following is the initial parts of my inputstream.

```
?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

Any solution?

Comment: There is a "less than" sign preceding the first question mark, right? That is just a formatting bug in the post, I assume.

Comment: Hi John, actually it was missing in the inputstream from the server. It was working in the old versions of android..  So I didn't care it so much. Since no other solutions worked out, I edidted the inputstream and it worked :-)... The exception was because of the missing "less than" symbol.. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 3):

The initial less-than sign is missing. Apparently older versions of android allowed this incorrect XML.

Comment: Copied from my earlier comment because it turned out to be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an inputSource for the documentBuilder:

```
Document doc = null;
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml)); //where xml is you xml file
doc = db.parse(is);
```

Hope this helps.